# Correct term for higher-dimensional analogue of a cyclic polygon?

Tags: geometry, terminology

A $d$-dimensional polytope whose vertices lie on the boundary of some $d$-dimensional sphere is called a *cyclic polygon* when $d=2$. Is there a succinct name for this in higher dimensions?